# Is it possible to make link clickable inside <input> tag angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

HTML

```
<input type="text" placeholder="enter link here..." name="link" ng-model="link"/>
```

Controller::

```
$scope.link = "https://stackoverflow.com"
```

When clicking on the link inside input box, it should clickable and redirected to StackOverflow page.

Comment: try `<textarea>` instead, or some WYSIWYG text editor

Comment: Thanks, Aleksey but according to my requirements, I must use input tag. Is it possible?

Comment: describe how you expect it to work, maybe there is a workaround. Otherwise it will not work

Comment: You can also trigger an `ng-click` to simulate a redirection: [Plunker demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/3Kf9iUiGNVILaOIax23Q?p=preview)

Comment: but we can not add some new text inside input tag

Comment: try this updated version: [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/QdOAsBf6X52LryexqXPq?p=preview). But you can't really have an input with a link, only simulate it with `ng-click`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regex for making clickable URL in the string

**In controller:**

```
    var regex = '/(\b(ftp|http|https):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/ig'
    var link = "https://stackoverflow.com";

  var clickableLink =  link.replace(regex, function (url) {
     return '<a target="_blank" href="' + url + '">' + url + '</a>';
  });
 console.log("clickableLink::", clickableLink);
```

Answer (score 0):

it's not an angular question, but rather a DOM one.

an input element can't contain childNodes, hence the answer is no,
However, using [contentEditable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Editable_content) something like this is quite possible:

```css
.pseudo-input {
  width: 250px;
  height: 30px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  line-height: 30px;
}

.pseudo-input a {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="pseudo-input" contenteditable>
You can <a href="http://google.com" target="_blank">click me!</a>
</div>
```